# qmail installation on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, email

I just tried to install qmail on my server running Ubuntu 10.04

I followed all the instructions but it seems that svscan /service is not running on my machine. How do I fix it?

AFAIK, it should be added to qmailctl start, but I am not so sure. Its probably because of how  Ubuntu handles the start of services via upstart, but yet again, I am not sure.

Thanks for taking time to help me :)

Comment: Remember to sacrifice a goat to DJB if you plan to succeed.

Comment: who might that be?

Comment: So what is in the logs? Why use qmail? Is there a reason not to use Ubuntu's standard MTA?

Comment: just want to learn qmail. the logs indicate that svscan /service was not started(as in never even called). if i run it manually, things work just fine.

Comment: DJB is the author or qmail :)